# Split a row with long text (listed items) on it into 2 rows automatically whenever goes through the next page

Tags: tables, longtable, itemize

I need a table looks like

[image]

. I know it seems impossible to break 1 row goes through to the next page, but this screenshot is taken from a LaTeX document, so maybe there's a possibility to do this. My table contains a listed items and it needs to break the row because it doesn't fit on one page.

If you don't mind please don't ask me the reason why i'm doing this. Just say i'm learning a simple hack to overcome the impossible. By the way, i've read some possible duplicates using paracol or `\tabularnewline` but haven't found the best result. I don't know how to use paracol with repeated top row, double `\hline`, or i don't know to split the listed items using `\tabularnewline`. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{longtable, array,enumitem, booktabs, lipsum}

\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitem]{label=\textbullet, noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt, nosep, before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}, after=\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{longtable}{p{2cm}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2cm-4\tabcolsep}}
        \caption{\label{tab}This is a table}\\
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 1}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 2}}\\
        \hline \hline
        \endfirsthead
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 1}}
        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Column 2}}\\
        \hline \hline
        \endhead 
        Point 1 & 
        \begin{tabitem}
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
        \end{tabitem}\\     
        \hline
        Point 2 & 
        \begin{tabitem}
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
            \item \lipsum[2]
        \end{tabitem}
          \\
        \hline
        Point 3 & Explanation \\
        \hline
        Point 4 & Explanation \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A `longtable` can only contain page breaks between table rows, not within them. To nevertheless get a page break in the middle of such a itemize list, place each item in its own table row.  Since the second line of each item in the table in the screenshot is not indented, it was probably created without the use of `itemeize` (or a similar environment) but with the use of `\textbullet` right before the text.

Comment: Ok sir thanks, but how do you say about the first item on the second row? It looks like the sentence goes through to the next page? Maybe a trick to split 1 row into 2 rows?

Comment: Oh, that's right. I didn't notice that. Something else, that makes me think, that actually no `itemize` environment was involved. If I had to guess, I'd say, the linebreaks within each item were created manually by placing each of the three lines of the last item on the first page into three different table rows.